# android app crashes when start and its only for android 8.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My android app crashes when start. Its problem was only with android 8.0.
Error from Google Console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3194)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3302)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (Unknown Source)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1891)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>         at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1081)
>         at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source:4)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7372)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1218)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3147)

Comment: Maybe you should post your code of UnityPlayerActivity's onCreate method and then other people can help you quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with API 27+. I'm back to 26 (it's bad, i know) and it's working okay.